# Replacing <font></font> properly

Tags: html, css, fonts, deprecated

```
'<font size="myfontSize">my text</font>'
```

What is the proper way for replacing this?
Now it is deprecated.

1)how to replace?
2)how to do the equivalent between the font sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the link
@HereticMonkey, and how do I do the font size equivalence? is the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "font size equivalence". Anything you would have put in `font size=""`, you can put in the `font-size: ` property of CSS.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they were equal, I thought there was some ratio difference.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change fonts, font size, font styling etc use CSS classes and CSS selectors to make the changes you want. Just like you would for any other page styling you'd need to do.

Below is a couple examples of replacing `<font>`.

```css
.text-lg {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.text-primary {
  color: blue;
}

.text-emphasized {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem <font size="7" color="blue">ipsum</font> dolor.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem <span class="text-lg text-primary">ipsum</span> dolor.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem <span class="text-emphasized">ipsum</span> dolor.
</p>
```